# Declarar items del DOM con $

Tags: jquery, dom

¿Es correcta la declaración con `$` para asignar items del DOM para trabajar con ellos posteriormente?

En caso de que no, ¿debería asignarlos a variables normales con `let`?

```
$table = $('#tblActividades');
$nuevo = $("#btnNuevo");
$buscar = $("#txtBuscar");
$ok = $("#ok");
$araba = $("#cmbAraba");
$bizkaia = $("#cmbBizkaia");
$gipuzkoa = $("#cmbGipuzkoa");

$nuevo.click(function () {
    AbrirModal(this);            
});
$ok.click(function () {
    RefrescarTabla();
});
```

Comment: Mira esta pregunta de SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/205853/why-would-a-javascript-variable-start-with-a-dollar-sign?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: tu pregunta aunque interesante, se basa en opiniones , creo que debes cambiarla para que no la cierren

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Es por convención el hecho de usar `$` para referirse a objetos del DOM accedidos mediante *jQuery*, por estética (para diferenciar qué variables se usarán del DOM en jQuery), pero no es necesario.
Pero siempre debes, como buena práctica, definir el ámbito de la variable (`var` = ámbito global | `let` = ámbito local), puedes usar siempre `var`, pero en algunos casos te puede interesar usar `var` también en ámbito local.

```
var $table = $('#tblActividades');
var $nuevo = $("#btnNuevo");
var $buscar = $("#txtBuscar");
var $ok = $("#ok");
var $araba = $("#cmbAraba");
var $bizkaia = $("#cmbBizkaia");
var $gipuzkoa = $("#cmbGipuzkoa");

$nuevo.click(function () {
    AbrirModal(this);            
});
$ok.click(function () {
    RefrescarTabla();
});
```

O bien

```
let $table = $('#tblActividades');
let $nuevo = $("#btnNuevo");
let $buscar = $("#txtBuscar");
let $ok = $("#ok");
let $araba = $("#cmbAraba");
let $bizkaia = $("#cmbBizkaia");
let $gipuzkoa = $("#cmbGipuzkoa");

$nuevo.click(function () {
    AbrirModal(this);            
});
$ok.click(function () {
    RefrescarTabla();
});
```

Pero siempre debes definir las variables, puedes tener muchos errores si no lo haces..

Comment: Por favor. Corrige lo que dices de Var. Var se puede utilizar tanto global como localmente. Como lo estás explicando en este momento da a entender que Var es sólo utilizada en ámbito global y esto no es correcto

Comment: @Huskie Pero por temas de convención y buena práctica debe hacerse de esa forma. Tampoco es estrictamente necesario definir las variables siquiera, pero es una mala práctica, al igual que definir como `var` una variable que se va a usar en ámbito local únicamente, es por tener un código limpio, comprensible, y legible. Se pueden hacer muchas cosas, pero que se pueda hacer no quiere decir que están bien :) Si tienes documentación que diga lo contrario, por favor pásamela porque yo no la he encontrado y a lo mejor me equivoco

Comment: Aún así editaré para que se entienda mejor.

Comment: Te vuelves a equivocar. Esta perfectamente aceptado el uso de var en ámbito local de hecho en muchas librerías de js se utiliza así. El código limpio, comprensible y legible no tiene nada que ver con el ámbito que posea Var. Además vuelvo y te repito como lo comentas estás dando mal la información. Por darte un ejemplo sencillo, revisa la librería jquery. Hay var definidas en ámbito local en abundancia

Comment: @Huskie No te preocupes por eso, lo entiendo perfectamente, estamos para intentar ayudar en la medida de lo posible, siempre es aceptado un comentario amigable :) Añado, no obstante un [ejemplo de lo que quiero decir con lo de var  o let](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/274342/is-there-any-reason-to-use-the-var-keyword-in-es6)

Comment: @enriquemanzanogil el problema de definir var local es que var es accesible desde fuera del ambito local tambien. Al contrario que let, que es accesible solo donde es declarado. ¿No?

Comment: Aquí tienes alguna documentación para que observes que la implementación de var no es sólo global y que está perfectamente aceptado (no es mala práctica ni nada por el estilo) su uso en ámbito local. Enlace 1: [js scope](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp) y enlace 2: [ámbito variables js](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/bzt2dkta(v=vs.94).aspx)

Comment: Tal cual @GDP. Es lo que intento mencionar que var puede ser tanto local como global. Sólo se diferencia de let porque let fuera del bloque, función, etc no existe

Comment: Eso lo entiendo, pero el hecho es que si dentro de una función defines un `var` puedes usarlo dentro de otra función que se halle dentro de esta, pero con let restringes ese paso. No son iguales, y claro que se puede usar, pero si no tienes necesidad de usarlas fuera del bloque, sigue siendo preferible utilizar `let` , [Aquí ejemplo de MDN de por qué viene bien diferenciarlas siempre](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/let)

Comment: @Huskie y comprendo perfectamente lo que dices, a lo mejor no he usado la expresión correcta, pero las cosas en programación, mientras más estrictas las dejes, mejor suele ser siempre :)

Comment: Ni modo. Aunque tu respuesta es correcta en términos generales aquel usuario que lea (y sepa poco) de var y let terminará entendiendo que var sólo se usa en ámbito global y esto no es cierto. Pero bueno solo intentaba mejorar tu respuesta para que sea útil no sólo al OP sino a todo SOes.

Comment: Listo @enriquemanzanogil eso era todo! xD! ya puedo darte el +1 con alegría! jaja

Comment: @Huskie editado de nuevo, sigo diciendo, siempre es mejor usar lo que más se ajusta, si no vas a salir del ámbito local, siempre va a ser mejor utilizar let, aunque var sea válida.

Comment: @Huskie jajaja, bueno, siempre es mejor intentar llegar a un consenso, mediante la discusión del tema :)

Comment: xD! Toda la razón @enriquemanzanogil. Un saludo. Espero que más usuarios puntuen tu valioso aporte!

Comment: @Huskie Muchas gracias amigo, espero seguir viéndote activo y que podamos discutir de estos temas, en pos del auto-aprendizaje :D

Comment: por buenas practicas se recomienda declarar las variables del DOM como const y para saber que son del DOM se recomienda anteponer el $ , pero esto lo recomienda los programadores de JavaScript Nativos pero si usas jQuery puedes confundirte, igual es bueno que coloques var, let o const esto para evitar el "use strict"